Issue with vertices creating a triangular area on a mesh
I need help with a particular area on my model.

The issue here is that I don't know how to fix it.
Do I make loop cuts on both of the sides of the model, risking cluttering it, or do I simply go on with it and fill it up with a face as it's a placeholder model for a player character for a game project.
Also here's the .blend file


It seems that you would simply want to decide how many faces you'd like to fill up that gap.   Select all 3 vertices and 'f' (add face), or sibdivide the edges and fill in each triplet of vertices to eventually fill all that in.  Am I missing something?  It looks like you don't need much detail.

Yeah, the idea behind it all is that it's gonna be pretty low-poly. Though game engines like Godot should be able to handle triangles on meshes right? I heard somewhere that game engines generally prefer 4 verts, especially when animating.

@prox-ee https://www.dragonflydb.io/faq/why-game-engines-use-triangles

Also note that whatever shape the faces end up, you can apply the "Triangulate" modifier, but of course that can unnecessarily increase the poly count.
